# Facebook session get closed when trying to post status

Tags: android, facebook

here is my code for updating status:

```
new Session(context);
Session.setActiveSession(session);
Session.openActiveSession(context);
Log.e("session after setted",Session.getActiveSession().toString());

Request request = Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
    // If the response is successful
       if (Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) {
            if (user != null) {
                session = Session.getActiveSession();
            postFromAlarm();
                Log.e("user","not null");
            }else{
            postFromAlarm();
            Log.e("user","null");
        }
        }  else{
        postFromAlarm();
        Log.e("not open session",Session.getActiveSession().toString());
        Log.e("session","not open");
        }
     }   
}); 
Log.e("request session",request.getSession().toString());
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

`Log.e("session after setted",Session.getActiveSession().toString());`
is showing a good and healthy session, which can be used for posting. because in logcat, it is showing that the session is open, accesstoken is good, app_id is also good.

but using this session when i am trying to post, in the `onComplete()` method, executed these lines:

`Log.e("not open session",Session.getActiveSession().toString());
 Log.e("session","not open");`

and it is showing that:

`{Session state:CLOSED, token:null, appId:***************** }`

what is wrong? i have tried without `new Session(context)`, but getting the same result. what should i do?

Comment: do you close the session anywhere in your code? The newMeRequest is executed asynchronously, so it's possible that the session is closed elsewhere. If not, please post more complete code, this sample is not enough to show the problem.

Comment: yes, i have closed the session before. but before i closed the session, i have saved the open session in file and then i am trying to set the active session with the saved session. if my procedure is wrong, is there any other option to send request with my saved session??  @MingLi

Comment: Do not save the session, and do not reuse a closed session, just create a new one. It's cheap to create, and if the user has already authorized the app (you can check because the session will be in CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED state), then you can open it without any user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save the session when you create it for first time using

```
SessionStore.save(mFacebook, getBaseContext());
```

and also restore the session when same user performs post operation

```
SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, getBaseContext());
```

where `mFacebook` is your `Facebook` object reference

Comment: there are so many session i have to handle. so i can't store just one session. and i cannot find any `SessionStore class` in Facebook sdk 3.02, would you please help me, if i am missing something. @TechKida

Comment: try this Lorenz's tutorial http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-use-facebook-sdk-to-post-status-from-android/ it helped me a lot